# What are the origins of the name "scanf" and the specifier "%g"?

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

What does the `"f"` in `'scanf'` mean?

Also, why are double values signified by `"%g"` - what does the `g` mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about a practical programming problem, as laid out in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that the `f` means that the function takes a *format specifier*, as does `printf()`.

`%g` = `%f + 1`, I guess, as `%d` was taken for "decimal integer".

Full list, with descriptions, can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

Comment: Awesome.  "g" makes sense since doubles can also take "%e" and "%f".  I searched Google with your "float" suggestion and found this: [Beej's Guide to C](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/scanf.html).  So might it be possible the "f" means "f"ormatted string, or "f"ile ?

Comment: @trojanfoe, I think he's referring to the actual "f" at the end of the function name ("scanf"), which stands for "formatted" as he notes. It does not stand for "file." That's `fscanf()`.